# AliasManagerInterface -deprecated Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManagerInterface

Tags: 8, path-aliases, dependency-injection

Error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
> TypeError: Argument passed to Drupal{module name}\Theme{class
> name}::__construct() must implement interface
> Drupal\path_alias\AliasManagerInterface, instance of
> Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManager

Getting error in the construct method, please suggest a solution to rectify the error.

Try to modify the "AliasManagerInterface" as "use Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManagerInterface" deprecated and we are now using "use Drupal\path_alias\AliasManagerInterface" but actually getting error inside construct method as mentioned below.

code:

```
 use Drupal\path_alias\AliasManagerInterface;



  /**
   * Protected pathAlias variable.
   *
   * @var Drupal\path_alias\AliasManagerInterface
   */
  protected $pathAlias;


  public function __construct(AliasManagerInterface $pathAlias) {
    
    $this->pathAlias = $pathAlias;

  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You must be on Drupal 8.8, or Drupal 8.9.

Drupal8, until 8.7, declared the `path.alias_manager` service, that referred to `Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManager`. In Drupal 8.8, that service was deprecated, to be removed in Drupal 9.x. A new service was introduced as a replacement, the `path_alias.manager` service, which refers to `Drupal\path_alias\AliasManager`.

The dependency injection from the original question is expecting an object of implementing the interface `Drupal\path_alias\AliasManagerInterface`, and the `path_alias.manager` service does implement this interface. However, the error says that the dependency injection is not receiving an object that implements `Drupal\path_alias\AliasManagerInterface`, it is incorrectly receiving an object of type `Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManager`, giving you the error.

The original question does not show how the dependency is being generated, but in Drupal the two most common methods are creating a service and declaring dependencies in the `*.services.yml` file for the module, or in the `create()` method of the class. Whichever method was used, is still using the old `path.alias_manager` service, and therefore passing `Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManager` to the class instead of `Drupal\path_alias\AliasManager`. The solution is to change service being injected from `path.alias_manager` to `path_alias.manager`.

Further reading: https://www.drupal.org/node/3092086